# Generate correlated random numbers precisely

Tags: statistics, random, correlation

Let's assume I want to generate *k* samples of *n* random numbers, that are correlated according to a given correlation matrix *C* (e.g. $n = 3$):

```
1    0.3  0.3
0.3    1  0.3
0.3  0.3    1
```

Using Cholesky Decomposition (Python implementation from NumPy), I can calculate *L* so $C = LL^T$:

```
L = [[ 1.          0.          0.        ]
     [ 0.3         0.9539392   0.        ]
     [ 0.3         0.22013982  0.92819096]]
```

Generating *n* (uncorrelated) random numbers (using *numpy.random.normal($\mu$, $\sigma$)*) and multiplying each the vector with *L* should result in one sample with *n* correlated random variables. – So far my understanding of the algorithm.

When I check the random numbers with SPSS, the "observed" correlations differ from the ones given in *C*. Example: I choose $n = 3$, $k = 10 000$ and $r = 0.99$. The observed correlations are:

```
     V1        V2        V3
V1     1          .774      .578
V2      .774     1          .443
V3      .578      .443     1
```

For my use-case I will need random numbers, that represent the given correlation matrix precisely. Did I make a mistake in this process or did I misunderstand the algorithm? Some insight is much appreciated.

Comment: I found my mistake: I calculated $R_c = L \cdot R$ which is valid as long as $L$ is the upper triangle. As you can see in my question, my algorithm produces the lower triangle, i.e. $L^T$. I just had to change my code and either reverse the order of my multiplication ($R_c = R \cdot L^T$) or transpose the algorithm's result ($R_c = (L^T)^T \cdot R = L \cdot R$). Now, my observed correlations are close enough to the specified.

Comment: Can you clarify what $r$ is?

Comment: @daaxix: In the example I used equal correlations $r$ across the correlation matrix.